# debhelper error with Sphinx: is is not in the index; is it up-to-date?

Tags: python-sphinx, debhelper

Several debian packages fail to build with the following error.

"dh_sphinxdoc: error: 1.0/jquery-3.5.1.js is not in the index; is it up-to-date?"

It's not clear why this error is being generated, or what actions would resolve it. Some advice?

I tried to read the sphinx source code in order to find what steps would trigger an update of some kind of index. I tried searching for issues with debhelper and sphinx. I expected an error message which explains what the problem is and why it is a problem.

Comment: Perhaps https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/changes.html#id41?